# Determine which JavaScript functions were NOT called

Tags: javascript, browser, google-chrome-devtools

Imagine you have a website which uses some JavaScript libraries, be it your own or third-party authored. In addition to minimizing and obfuscating, I was wondering if it would be possible to further reduce the size of the script payload by removing unused functions. Once you reach a certain level of complexity, it becomes difficult/impossible to know which functions end up getting called under all possible execution paths. And that led me to have this question: are there any tools or any ways to determine, after a period of usage of the web page, what user-defined functions (not built-in ones) have not been called?

One obvious possibility would be to wrap all function definitions in a call to a registration function, which 1) adds the function to a registrar, and 2) injects some code to mark the function as having been called. Then it would be possible to query the registrar of functions for those that haven't been called. However, this approach is extremely complicated. The best bet is to write a JavaScript code parser on the web server, which is enabled by a runtime flag ("is in JS diagnostic mode"), which captures all JavaScript responses and modifies the code accordingly. But it doesn't take a lot of imagination to realize how error prone and difficult this would be.

**UPDATE**: just to clarify, I'm not looking for a solution which automatically removes unused functions, I wouldn't be comfortable with that, for fear of introducing instability. Rather, development time analysis of function usage would let me choose which includes/functions to remove, so that the final solution can then be properly tested before being released.

Comment: Please refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This is a problem known as tree shaking. Webpack includes some utilities to facilitate it. It's a big subject, and there are a lot of resources available to help with it.

Comment: @CharlesBamford: From what I understand, tree shaking is just the ECMAScript community's name for *dead code elimination* and is done *statically*, whereas the OP is asking about doing it *dynamically*, because doing it statically is actually equivalent to solving the Halting Problem.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I'd clarify that there are few issues with static analysis: 1) it will never yield results which are as accurate as dynamic analysis, since real life user input isn't considered; 2) while it **could** be achieved (like Webpack's approach - by using the concept of "entry point"), it's even more complicated - instead of just looking for function definitions and injecting some code around it, you're now looking at deep dive parsing and interpreting the entire codebase, which, given how flexible JavaScript is, is even more error prone.

Comment: It may be possible to override Function.prototype.call with something to log when a function is called. A brief bit of experimentation suggested that it's possible. It's contrary to best practices, obviously, but W3C isn't my real dad anyway. If you compile a list of all the functions in your code base, you could subtract the list of called functions.

Comment: Or if you have like real unt tests and acceptance tests, you yank out code and see if anything breaks.

Comment: @CharlesBamford great suggestion. In order to avoid wrapping every function definition in registration boilerplate, I had another idea - maybe enumerate all functions starting at `window` and then go down recursively to create the list of functions.

Comment: @CharlesBamford Monkeypatching `Function.prototype.call` won't help as functions are usually called directly. You would have to call every method using its prototype `call` function.

Comment: Dead code elimitation is definitely possible, albeit difficult. You could use babel as lexer and parser to obtain an AST. Convert that to a CFG and perform data flow analysis on it. With that information you'll be able to compute constant coditions and drop pathes that can never be reached. You can also drop any code that isn't connected to the CFG at all. If you're interested in writing a compiler that does dead code elimination, read [this paper](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~lopes/teaching/inf212W12/readings/rep-analysis-soft.pdf).

Comment: The easiest way to wrap all your functions would be to write a babel-plugin that transpiles your code, wrapping every function. That should be fairly straightforward and you wouldn't have to touch your code base, you could simply produce two versions of your code, one with the transformation and one without.

Answer (score 2):

> Once you reach a certain level of complexity, it becomes difficult/impossible to know which functions end up getting called under all possible execution paths.

There is no need for the slash in "difficult/impossible". *Dead code elimination* is equivalent to solving the Halting Problem and is thus straight-up impossible, period.

> are there any tools or any ways to determine, after a period of usage of the web page, what user-defined functions (not built-in ones) have not been called?

This sits somewhere in between *profiling* (determining which parts of the code have been executed how often) and *coverage analysis* (determining which parts of the code have been executed at all). More precisely, it sounds like you are looking for *function coverage*.

Note that code coverage is often talked about in the context of testing, so much so that for some people the terms "code coverage" and "test coverage" are synonymous, but code coverage has nothing to do with testing. It simply refers to the question "when I run a specific workload, which parts of the code get executed?"

There are different was how to interpret the term "part" in the question above, and they give rise to different kinds of coverage:

- *line coverage*: which lines get executed?
- *function coverage*: which functions get executed? (This is the one you are interested in.)
- *statement coverage*: which statements get executed?
- *expression coverage*: which expressions get executed?
- *branch coverage*: which branches of a conditional get executed?
- *path coverage*: which paths through a block get executed?

Line coverage is typically not useful because you can change the number simply by re-formatting your code. In fact, in ECMAScript, I can trivially always make it so that all lines are executed by simply writing everything on one line.

The difference between branch coverage and path coverage can be exemplified by this piece of code:

```js
function foo(bar, baz) {
  if (bar) {
    console.log("bar");
  } else {
    console.log("no bar");
  }

  if (baz) {
    console.log("baz");
  } else {
    console.log("no baz");
  }
}
```

In order to cover all *branches*, I need *two* calls:

```js
foo(true,  false);
foo(false, true);
```

In order to cover all possible *paths* through the function, I need *four* calls:

```js
foo(true,  true);
foo(true,  false);
foo(false, true);
foo(false, false);
```

If you do heuristic dead code elimination based on function coverage, you will be able to delete unused functions. If you do it based on branch coverage, you will be able to even delete unused branches from `if` or `switch` statements.

If you are looking for code coverage tools, you will probably have to look in the testing space, since that is where they are most often used. And you will probably have to write your own dead code elimination tool, or maybe patch an existing minifier so that it can read a log file from a code coverage run and make decisions based on that.

As far as I know, there are no existing tools to do that, although I might be wrong.

Comment: Removing *all* dead code is equivalent to the halting problem. Removing most dead code is just difficult, and there are definitely low-hanging fruit.

Comment: Well, the OP is asking about what to do after all statically recognizable dead code has already been removed.

Comment: Yeah, I think they want to find live code (that *could* be used) that is not used in a typical session. (I'd argue that this is a bad idea, as for atypical sessions the page would simply break, e.g. when error-handlers are removed that are *normally* unused).

Comment: Definition: *heuristics* – what you thought you knew and discovered at the worst possible time you don't. There's this great story I don't know actually how much truth there is to it, that 90% of users only use 10% of MS Word. So, if you used coverage analysis, you would delete 90% of code, but actually *every single line of code* that is there, was put there based on a feature request of someone who needs it, so if you delete *just one* of those "unused" lines, you have broken someone's Word.